# How do I search with Excel for cells with specific characters at the end of the string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to know how to use pattern matching in excel.

Suppose I have 3 cells...

ABC

ABD

JGFC

I need to highlight those with C **AT THE END**.

This is a small example. I need to do similar stuff for hundreds of cells. It's very frustrating and sometimes I'll miss several. I need a fast and reliable way.

Comment: When you say "highlight", do you mean you need to format them or you need to select them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific example, you can use `=RIGHT(A1,1)="C"`.

Depending on how similar your other use cases are, you may also want to look into the `LEFT()`, `MID()` and `FIND()` formulae. For complex pattern matching, you may need to resort to VBA to implement a [regex-based match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops).